# Html code to Hide Ribbon based on user permission in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, ribbon, custom-masterpage

I applied a custom master page,I need to hide the SharePoint 2013 ribbon based on user permission, I need Html Code same as

`<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="ManageWeb">
 <div id="s4-ribbonrow" …</div>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822366.aspx

Comment: can you provide details about your SharePoint version(2010 or 2013 on-premises or SP Online)

Comment: Dear @coc2coc he mentioned above at question it's  2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Edit your custom Master Page (HTML File)>
- To hide the ribbon for all user

> ```
> < div id="ms-designer-ribbon" style="display: none !important;" >
> ```

- To hide the ribbon based on the PermissionString

> ```
> <!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server"  
> PermissionsString="FullMask">-->
> Put the whole DIV of **ms-designer-ribbon**
> <!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>-->
> ```

To be like

[image]

In `PermissionsString` attribute, you can add any permission type based on your requirement from the following:

- FullMask.
- EmptyMask.
- ManagePermissions.
- ManageSubwebs.
- ManageWeb.
- AddAndCustomizePages.
- BrowseDirectories.
- ViewPages.
- EnumeratePermissions.
- ManageAlerts.

Check the detail steps at

- [How to hide SharePoint 2013 Ribbon based on permission](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/12/how-to-hide-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2013-using-css/)
- [How to hide SharePoint 2010 Ribbon](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/27/how-to-hide-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2010-using-css/)

Comment: Great Its working,but I can't scroll down the page?@Qassas

Comment: Is the scroll bar disabled or not exist ?

Comment: Scroll is not exist@Qassas

Comment: Should you tell me what's the type of master page , Oslo , settle , v4 ... custom master page , also are you tried diff browser

Comment: anyway find  this s4-workspace at your master page if exist try to add this style , #s4-workspace {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

Comment: I am using custom master page,I added that style,Then also i can't scroll the page,It looks like fixed.@Qassas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45097/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-suriyaadevan-balu).